# how to pass a variable of one class to multiple classes in python

Tags: python, class, pass-by-reference

I'm having problem with passing value/object from one class to another. My code as below. When I invoke the method `mainFunction()` , all the calls work fine, but it is failing `self.stub.call_method()` . Not sure why. When I declare the stub as a global variable, and then use it it works perfectly fine. The `Bar()` is another class which has remote invocation methods and one being `call_method()` . Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

The failure I meant is, the call reaches till call_method() and the call_method has some http invocation and it is unable to do the http invocation and throws HTTP Exception.

```
class Command(object):
     def dosomething(self):
         return 0
class Connect(Command):
     def __init__(self, value1, stub):
         self.value1 = value1
         self.stub = stub
     def dosomething(self):
         self.stub.call_method()
class Osclass(object):
     def __init__(self, val1):
        self.val1 =val1
        stub=Bar(value)
        self.stub = stub
     def activemethod(self):
        return Connect(self.val1, self.stub)

def mainFunction(val1, Osclass):
    ret_value = Osclass.activemethod()
    ret_value.execute()
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please clearly define `failing` .
Also I do not see `Osclass` having a function `foo` but you are using that in `mainFunction()` how is that working?

Comment: For `Connect` class, you do not have any execute statement, but you are trying to call it in `mainFunction` , again some peices missing? Also, if the issue still exists, please update the Bar class as well

Comment: Show how you're invoking ``mainFunction`` and your ``Bar`` definition.  At very least, your usage of ``Bar(value)`` will fail because ``value`` isn't defined.  Also, be wary of defining an argument to ``mainFunction`` with the identifier of ``Osclass``, since you already have a class definition with the same name.

Comment: Please, post the code as you have it, along with the error message you are getting when you try to run it. The listing above does not make sense at all, and trying to match what it does (actually, what it does not) with the problem you are claiming to have is just consuming people time around here.